# Replace first two whitespace occurrences with a comma using sed

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, command-line, sed

I have a whitespace delimited file with a variable number of entries on each line. I want to replace the first two whitespaces with commas to create a comma delimited file with three columns.

Here's my input:

```
a b  1 2 3 3 2 1
c d  44 55 66 2355
line http://google.com 100 200 300
ef jh  77 88 99
z y 2 3 33
```

And here's my desired output:

```
a,b,1 2 3 3 2 1
c,d,44 55 66 2355
line,http://google.com,100 200 300
ef,jh,77 88 99
z,y,2 3 33
```

I'm trying to use perl regular expressions in a sed command but I can't quite get it to work. First I try capturing a word, followed by a space, then another word, but that only works for lines 1, 2, and 5:

```
$ cat test | sed -r 's/(\w)\s+(\w)\s+/\1,\2,/'
a,b,1 2 3 3 2 1
c,d,44 55 66 2355
line http://google.com 100 200 300
ef jh  77 88 99
z,y,2 3 33
```

I also try capturing whitespace, a word, and then more whitespace, but that gives me the same result:

```
$ cat test | sed -r 's/\s+(\w)\s+/,\1,/'
a,b,1 2 3 3 2 1
c,d,44 55 66 2355
line http://google.com 100 200 300
ef jh  77 88 99
z,y,2 3 33
```

I also try doing this with the .? wildcard, but that does something funny to line 4.

```
$ cat test | sed -r 's/\s+(.?)\s+/,\1,/'
a,b,1 2 3 3 2 1
c,d,44 55 66 2355
line http://google.com 100 200 300
ef jh,,77 88 99
z,y,2 3 33
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this:

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/,/' | sed -e 's/\s\+/,/'
```

It's probably possible with a single sed command, but this is sure an easy way :)

My output:

```
a,b,1 2 3 3 2 1
c,d,44 55 66 2355
line,http://google.com,100 200 300
ef,jh,77 88 99
z,y,2 3 33
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I was definitely making this too complicated!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sed -r 's/\s+(\S+)\s+/,\1,/'
```

Just replaced `\w` (one "word" char) with `\S+` (one or more non-space chars) in one of your attempts.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide multiple commands to a single instance of `sed` by just providing multiple `-e` arguments.

To do the first two, just use:

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/,/' -e 's/\s\+/,/'
```

This basically runs both commands on the line in sequence, the first doing the first block of whitespace, the second doing the next.

The following transcript shows this in action:

```
pax$ echo 'a b  1 2 3 3 2 1
c d  44 55 66 2355
line http://google.com 100 200 300
ef jh  77 88 99
z y 2 3 33
' | sed -e 's/\s\+/,/' -e 's/\s\+/,/'

a,b,1 2 3 3 2 1
c,d,44 55 66 2355
line,http://google.com,100 200 300
ef,jh,77 88 99
z,y,2 3 33
```

Answer (score 2):

Sed `s///` supports a way to say which occurrence of a pattern to replace: just add the `n` to the end of the command to replace only the `n`th occurrence. So, to replace the first and second occurrences of whitespace, just use it this way:

```
$ sed 's/  */,/1;s/  */,/2' input
a,b ,1 2 3 3 2 1
c,d ,44 55 66 2355
line,http://google.com 100,200 300
ef,jh ,77 88 99
z,y 2,3 33
```

**EDIT**: reading another proposed solutions, I noted that the `1` and `2` after `s/  */,/` is not only unnecessary but plainly wrong. By default, `s///` just replaces the first occurrence of the pattern. So, if we have two identical `s///` in sequence, they will replace the first and the second occurrence. What you need is just

```
$ sed 's/  */,/;s/  */,/' input
```

(Note that you can put two sed commands in one expression if you separate them by a semicolon. Some sed implementations do not accept the semicolon after the `s///` command; use a newline to separate the commands, in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution is:

```
perl -pe '$_=join ",", split /\s+/, $_, 3' some.file
```

Comment: Another Perl solution can't hurt, since the question was tagged with both Perl and Sed tags.

`perl -pe 's/([^\s,]+)\s/$1.(my$c++<3&& ",")." "/eg'`

I actually like the join/split method shown in the same thread better, but with a little work there is a s///eg alternative.  This method keeps track of how many substitutions have been performed and only subs in a comma the first three times for each line.  Maybe someday there will be a /g{3} option to constrain a m//g or s///g to three matches.

Comment: At least use auto split if using Perl. ;-)

Comment: Eg: `perl -anE 'say "$F[0],$F[1],$F[2] $F[3..$#F]"'`

Comment: I suppose it should be `perl -anE 'say "$F[0],$F[1],$F[2] @F[3..$#F]"'`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about sed/perl, but here's an (ugly) awk solution. It just prints fields 1-2, separated by commas, then the remaining fields separated by space:

```
awk '{
  printf("%s,", $1)
  printf("%s,", $2)
  for (i=3; i<=NF; i++)
    printf("%s ", $i)
    printf("\n")
}' myfile.txt
```