# another line split (powershell or other scripting tools under windows)

Tags: powershell

i have a log file in hand, looks like this:
0226 111641 (1911) 0 some space separated message containing whatever letters and marks

I need to import it to database, to use filters on it, when troubleshooting is needed. Currently i think powershell is best selection to achieve this, but i'm too green to know specifically how to do it so it can perform actually. I tried to do it like this:

```
$file = Get-Content "test.txt"

foreach ($line in $file)
    {
    #Write-Host $line
    $a = $line
    $month1 = $a[0..1]
    $month2 = "$month1"
    $month2 = $month2.ToString()
    $month = $month2.Replace(" ", "")

    $day1 = $a[2..3]
    $day2 = "$day1"
    $day2 = $day2.ToString()
    $day = $day2.Replace(" ", "")
}
```

... and so on. after that inserting it to database. However, log file is quite big (currently 15MB in 3 weeks, expected to be hundreds of megabytes within months), and already the script takes about 4-5min to process it. 
So what i need is method to split four space separated columns from beginning of the line, convert first and second to date and time and add them with message part of the line to database. Separately processing each block of text seems too time consuming, excel for example can process this file within seconds. Is there around some position aware csv-import command?

Thanks.

Found this:
[Replace first two whitespace occurrences with a comma using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618705/replace-first-two-whitespace-occurrences-with-a-comma-using-sed)
would help, if i would use linux... :(

Comment: post a sample of original file and a sample of what you want achieve

Comment: What parts are what? Is `0226` the date? `111641` the time? What is `(1911) 0` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the `ConvertFrom-Csv` or `Import-Csv` cmdlets can help you since your field delimiter can appear in the message field.  Without knowing what these different fields are, I came up with this:

```
$file = Get-Content "test.txt"

foreach ($line in $file)
{
    # Split $line into at most 5 fields
    $fields = $line -split ' ', 5;
    # fields[0] is a two-digit month followed by a two-digit day
    $date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($fields[0], 'MMdd', $null);
    $field2 = $fields[1];
    $field3 = $fields[2];
    $field4 = $fields[3];
    $message = $fields[4];

    # Process variables here...
}
```

Using the sample text you provided for `$line`, the above variables look like this after execution:

```
PS> Get-Variable -Name @('date', 'field*', 'line', 'message')

Name                           Value
----                           -----
date                           2/26/2012 12:00:00 AM
field2                         111641
field3                         (1911)
field4                         0
fields                         {0226, 111641, (1911), 0...}
line                           0226 111641 (1911) 0 some space separated message
message                        some space separated message
```

More information will be needed on the format of your data in order to give you a more specific answer.